# How to solve this syntax error in NodeJS MySQL?

Tags: mysql, node.js

Getting a syntax error here but can't figure out why?

Have tried using con.escape as well. Gives the same error.

```
var sql1 = "INSERT INTO Captcha (Captcha_Image) VALUES ('"+imgBase64+"') WHERE Session_ID = '"+x+"'";
  await con.query(sql1, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 record inserted");
  });

//Both imgBase64 and x are varchar values and are being stored in correctly
```

how to solve this ***error***:

> Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'WHERE Session_ID =
>   '93e23e3f7d17b1c50107aa6277cb303985e38e1a5faa0a505064806c291a' at line
>   1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert statements in SQL don't have a `WHERE` clause, so the following should work without error:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({ ... });

var sql1 = "INSERT INTO Captcha (Captcha_Image) VALUES (?)";
con.query({
    sql: sql1,
    timeout: 40000,
},
    [imgBase64],
    function (error, results, fields) {
    }
);
```

However, a `WHERE` clause might make sense if you were doing an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`, with a select query serving as the source of data to be inserted.  Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Captcha (Captcha_Image)
SELECT Captcha_Image
FROM some_other_table
WHERE Session_ID = '93e23e3f7d17b1c50107aa6277cb303985e38e1a5faa0a505064806c291a';
```

If you instead want to change the Captcha image for records which already exist in the table, based on the session id, then you should be doing an *update*, not an insert:

```
con.query('UPDATE Captcha SET Captcha_Image = ? WHERE Session_ID = ?',
    [imgBase64, x],
    function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log('changed ' + results.changedRows + ' rows');
    }
);
```

Comment: So is there no way to add the value while checking for a particular ID?

Comment: _What_ are you trying to check?  By definition, the records you are trying to insert aren't even in the database table yet.

Comment: They are inserted earlier. This isn't the full code.

Comment: If the records are already in the table, and you want to change their values, then you should be doing an _update_, not an insert.  Let me edit my answer again.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clearer. I have a table setup where one column value is filled up while the other fields remain empty. Now I want to select this row using the already entered ID and fill up the rest of the fields.